# How to open local file in browser using xamarin?

Tags: file, xamarin, local

Im using xamarin and i want to open a local file (txt or pdf) in a browser directly frol the app.

So i do this :

```
 var uri = new System.Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
 await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
```

And I have the following exception :

```
System.ArgumentException : 'IDN labels must be between 1 and 63 characters long.
```

I think it's possible but i dont know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **don't** think you can open a local file (txt or pdf) in a browser directly from the app. The file is stored in your local path(not a web link) and the browser is not able to open it.

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios#files) to open a file in your app:

> This features enables an app to request other apps to open and view a
> file. Xamarin.Essentials will automatically **detect the file type
> (MIME) and request the file to be opened.**

The code example is :

```
var fn = "File.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
{
    File = new ReadOnlyFile(file)
});
```

If you want to open a web link with the browser, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=ios).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should checkout xamarin essentials file help in [This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)